# Deleting/Inserting values from PHP codes to microsoft ACCESS?

Tags: php, ms-access

As topic mentioned. How can you insert a record or delete a record using PHP code after connecting to Microsoft Access Database? Thank you!

Edit: I've successfully login with a user account and now i will like to insert records. As below is the code that has not been successful in inserting record.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "Welcome: ". $_SESSION['role'];
?>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if (!$_POST['submit'])
{  
?
<html>
<body>
<br><br>
<fieldset >  
Add a new user 
<br>
<br>
<label for='username'>Username: &nbsp;</label>  
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'/>  
<label for='password'>Password:&nbsp;</label>  
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />  
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
Role: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br>
<select name="role">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option VALUE="Administrator"> Administrator</option>
<option VALUE="Secretary"> Secretary</option> 
<option VALUE="Employee"> Employee</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />  
</form>
</fieldset>  
<table width=100%>
</html>
</body>
<?php
}
else
{
$conn=odbc_connect("employee","","") or die (odbc_errormsg());
if (!$conn)  
{
exit
("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO empTable (empID, password, Role, Days left in MC, Days left in   leave) VALUES" .
"('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[role]', 14, 14)";
$result=odbc_exec($conn,$query) or die ("result error ".odbc_error().'-'.odbc_errormsg());
odbc_fetch_row($result);
odbc_close($conn);
}
```

After clicking the submit button and when i refresh my database, nothing comes out. Why is that so? Thanks alot

Update: Added the POST[username], POST[password], POST[role] and it still does not work :(

Comment: I honestly don't know what the StackOverflow policy is on this, but to me it seems very strange to edit your question to be something *completely different*.  It makes the earlier answers look bizarre.  Consider asking a new question instead.

Comment: @Mike Yes, the policy is to let old questions stand. After all, the big idea of the site is that other people with the same question may find it, and not have to ask themselves. That's also why we encourage posters to accept an answer, so people of the future can tell what worked! (that and the sweet, sweet rep points.) The new question should be posted separately, so it can get a separate set of answers.

Comment: Yes sirs, I understand. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Don't make a mod have to lock a post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using XAMPP, it should have Mercury mail as a built-in service. Open the XAMPP control panel and start Mercury. Don't change anything. Keep the default values.

Then in your php.ini file, make sure these lines are not commented (remove ';' from the beginning of the line to un-comment it) in the 'Mail Function' section:

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started in connecting to your Access DB and how to run queries against it:

http://networking.mydesigntool.com/viewtopic.php?tid=263&id=31

Once you've done that, you'll be able to query the DB as you would any other (Taking consideration of course any access specific SQL limitations or advantages). You've mentioned other databases so I'm assuming you know the basics of querying a database for your `delete` and `select` needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `odb_connect` ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php)) and `odbc_exec` ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php)) functions from php.

Answer (score 0):

you must have a smtp hot to send emails in php. So just configure a smtp host in php.ini file. This smtp host and port details can be got from your internet provider.

I think you can also use smtp servers of gmail etc with authentication